# How to use column names input in shiny app in server?

Tags: r, shiny

I am sorry I am new here and tried to go through existing questions but could not get the answer to my question.

I am trying to make an app using shiny such that I allow the user to choose two column names using a select input widget from side panel and then show a bar plot using those two columns from a dataset of my choice currently loaded in the environment. The problem is that my dataset has all the columns as categorical character vectors and thus first I have to make a two column table using the table command. So I need to get the name from input and use it in table command but its not happening.

I am attaching my dataset, the ui.r and server.r.

here is a link to the archive. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3cafW7J7xSfQ2xuc04xQlJjRGc/edit?usp=sharing

Any help will be much appreciated.

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I used a `pageWithSidebar` UI but you can change to the fluid one. Added a histogram plot

UI.R

```
    library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Road Accident Analysis"),                

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId="cname1",choices=names(smpl),label="Variable1"),

    selectInput(inputId="cname2",choices=names(smpl),label="Variable2")
  ),                              

  mainPanel(                                   
    plotOutput("myplot")
  )
))
```

server.r

```
  smpl <-read.csv("smpl.csv")
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$myplot<-renderPlot({
   # my<-input$cname1
   # counts<-table(smpl$my)
    #View(counts)
    hist(smpl$X1st_Road_Number)

  })

})
```

Comment: for a dynamic plot pass the inputId in the hist function